# Start over with Laravel's migrations

Tags: database, laravel, testing

I'm working on a bigger Laravel project for a while and have currently over 70 migrations (using MySQL). I've never written tests (shame on me) and like to catch up on that now.
I've used foreign keys at the beginning. I've renamed some and then I removed them completely with subsequent migrations.

Now a temporary sqlite database should be used for testing. But as I was renaming fk's by name and MySQL's naming convention differs from the sqlite's, sqlite cannot find these. There are also a bunch of other errors.

I'm wondering if I could delete all my migrations and create a single migration which holds **all** the database structure of the current state. Starting from scratch, so to speak.

Is that advisable? What should happen to the *migrations* table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While developing you are usually just continually adding migrations to get the structure you need. If you are at a point you like the structure, you can definitely condense down your migrations.

Often times when someone is developing locally they might do this, as they get to a spot where they might want to start deploying the application they will condense down the migrations, as you know the structure you need and you don't need to 'go backwards' as this is the schema you need. You only need to worry about future changes.

On any system you haven't ran these migrations you will be perfectly fine as it will just run the first time and you will have your complete schema ready to go. If you already have migrations table and don't want to rollback, you are in a pickle ... you would have to manually alter the migrations table to remove all the migrations that don't exist any more basically and change the remaining one(s) to match what you have after your consolidation. (If you were hoping to be able to rollback/refresh ... but in reality you won't be rolling back or refreshing after a certain point, only moving forward [often due to not wanting to loss data])

There isn't really much to worry about in just condensing down your migrations ... they are your schema and if you know the schema you want, no need to step through 20 different migrations that might be altering the same tables numerous times to get to that final result.

Comment: I've written a completely new migration and ensured that it would deliver the exact same database structure as all of my previous migrations together. Then, I've manually edited the _migrations_ table. Thanks!